# Can we get which cell was touched based on uiview touch?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to know whether I can get which cell was touched depending on the touch or pan location ?

I can get the touch easily but on touch of the view (mostly pan location) I have to reflect changes on the collection view behind it.

For touch location I am doing simple pan gesture like this :

```
@objc func panButton(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        if pan.state == .began {

        } else if pan.state == .ended || pan.state == .failed || pan.state == .cancelled {

        } else {
            let location = pan.location(in: view)

            }
        }
    }
```

Is this possible ? how ? or any alternative way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [convert](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert) point from one view to another.

Comment: convert(_ point: CGPoint, from view: UIView?). In this point is touch location and uiview is collectionview ?

Comment: @sharadchauhan yep

Comment: @sharadchauhan then use indexPathForRowAtPoint and find cell where touch was made

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and will accept it if it works.